Unable to select "other data source" when creating linked server
I am unable to select the option for Other data source when creating a linked server in SSMS, because the option is completely grayed out. I have installed Microsoft OLE DB Driver (MSOLEDBSQL) for SQL Server but nothing shows up under Server Objects > Linked Servers > Providers.

The only errors I see in errorlog are about SSISScaleOutMaster160 failing to open the SSISDB database, but we don't have scale out enabled. This is all on an Enterprise Evaluation copy of SQL Server 2022, but I still have 48 days left on my evaluation.
I would appreciate any guidance in making the OLE DB drivers work so I can create a linked server using them. Thank you.

Are you sure you have the 64-bit version of the OLE DB driver?

What is the resultat from xp_enum_oledb_providets?

EXEC xp_enum_oledb_providers only produces "commands completed successfully", no providers are listed. I am sure I have the 64-bit version of the driver. I uninstalled and reinstalled the 64-bit version, and the 32-bit version won't even install on my server.
